# if statement to control input text in code behind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, code-behind

I need to create if statement to control input text for example; when user type blue, send message from code behind for next user in order to notify him or her blue is already typed.
Is there any solution:

```
        if (user.Text == "blue")
        {



        }
```

Comment: Your question is *extremely* unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Simple comparisons like this work fine wherever the code is - but you haven't explained your problem, or why you think you should be converting it to an integer.

Comment: I need to create if statement to control input text for example; when user type blue, send message from code behind for next user in order to notify him or her blue is already typed.
Is there any solution?

Comment: you're looking to do an Asyncronous callback. Basically you will use something along the lines of the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit to post your data to the server, and from there, check validity against whatever criteria. Unfortunately you haven't fully specified the criteria. Your `if` statement is "right" right now based on the criteria you specified.

Comment: I think Application level object or Static variable will resolve his issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put such value in `Static variable or Application level object`, so that value will be persisted across the user and you can check for your next user from static or application level variable.

Comment: could you give an example in code.  I have no idea