# control sessions in application asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0

I need to control sessions in my application for example; when user typed sam in text box, the next user can not type sam as sam already in use!  Any idea?

```
Application["UserName"] = user.Text;
if (Application["UserName"] == "sam")
{
}
```

Comment: You posted similar question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636323/if-statement-to-control-input-text-in-code-behind

Comment: You need to provide many more details about your specific situation, otherwise you will get very general answers that aren't too helpful to your specific situation.

Comment: I think you would be better served by finding a good tutorial to follow and study; you haven't specified if you're storing your user information into a database, a plain text file, entirely in memory, or completely hard-coded into your application (which is what this _looks_ like, but it sure wouldn't be fun to _use_). Stack Overflow is an excellent way to learn something specific, but I wouldn't recommend it for trying to learn from the ground up. Find a good ASP.net tutorial (try http://www.asp.net for starts?) to learn from -- and feel free to ask questions about the tutorials. :)

Comment: Thank you I just got my answer by ust_name. well I am new in ASP.net but not that new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer according to what i understood .it 's not that clear question.

Firstly : as said before the `session` is `per client`.so this not the answer ..

I make a sample :

aspx:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" ontextchanged="txt_name_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_message" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

.cs:

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            static int i =0;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (i > 0 && txt_name.Text == "sam")
                {
                    txt_name.Enabled = false;
                    txt_name.Text = string.Empty;
                    lbl_message.Text = "In use";

                }
                else
                {
                    txt_name.Enabled = true;
                    lbl_message.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            protected void txt_name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (txt_name.Text == "sam")
                {
                    i++;
                }

            }

       }
```

you can use Application variable instead of static variable as said before.

Answer (score 3):

A Session is specific to the current user. If another user accesses your site he will not be able to read the session values of other users. So you would be better of storing this information into the [Application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx) which is shared between all users. The documentation contains many examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `Application level variable instead of a Session variable,` because an application variable value will persist across the user . e.g.

```
Application["UserName"] = user.Text;
if (Application["UserName"] == "sam")
{
     labelMessage.Text = "This user has been already selected.";
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, but how to write a code to say that; if sam is already in use "do something"?

Comment: I need action when second person type sam

Comment: You can put label and display message to user. you can check similar example from this thread. At least you can have idea from this thread .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340314/is-there-any-email-already-exists-in-asp-net-functionality-with-validator/6340390#6340390

Comment: I need without use of ajax and database. just want to say when user typed blue for second type do something. The thing is, I do not know how to do it an I am sure there is a method to do it

Comment: is the above code for when user type for second time? I think it will be the same for first person as well!!